# Помогите правильно написать цикл в python с учетом значений из 3 столбцов

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть 3 столбца range_1, range_2, range_3:

| range_1 |
| --- |
| 26365 |
| 3757 |
| 3723 |

| range_2 |
| --- |
| -275,08 |
| 757,74 |
| 668,44 |

| range_3 |
| --- |
| -1 |
| 1 |
| -1 |

Также есть 2 значения sum_1 = 75644.

Нужно написать цикл который будет проверять значение столбца range_2 равняется ли оно максимальному значению данного столбца, если равняется, то необходимо прибавить значение range_3 к значению range_1 по строке, по которой было найдено максимальное значение. Цикл должен повторяться пока сумма значений по столбцу range_3 не достигнет sum_1.

```
def rounding(range_1, range_2, range_3, summ):
   if sum(range_1) != summ:
       for i in range_1:
            for j in range_2:
                for z in range_3:
                    if range_2[j] == max(range_2):
                        range_1[i] += range_3[z]
```

Выдает ошибку KeyError: -1.837480750236864

Подскажите как правильно написать цикл? Так как я не совсем понимаю как использовать в цикле значения двух столбцов. Пишу код на python. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А вообще вы зря создали копию вашего закрытого вопроса, такое обычно тут же закрывают без разговоров. Надо было подождать, пока первый ваш вариант восстановят после того как вы в него код добавили.

Comment: не совсем понятно, в вопросе у вас  `сумма значений по столбцу range_3 не достигнет sum_1`  а в коде проверяете  `if sum(range_1) != summ:`

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно проверять значения по всем трём столбцам **в одной и той же строке** и все столбцы имеют одно и то же число строк, то делается это по-другому - просто **итерируетесь по строке** и всё, индекс строки **один**, не нужно никаких вложенных циклов. Ну и не `if`, конечно, а цикл `while` должен быть:

```
while sum(range_1) != summ:
    for i in range(len(range_1)):
        if range_2[i] == max(range_2):
            range_1[i] += range_3[i]
```

А вообще числа с плавающей точкой - штука коварная, я не уверен, что точное совпадение будет достигнуто и цикл закончится. Возможно, нужно проверять совпадение с какой-то точностью, а не абсолютно.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, попробовал, всю равно выдает KeyError

Comment: @AlexSCH Приведите тогда пример `range_1`, `range_2`, `range_3` в виде питоновского кода, чтобы код можно было проверить на ваших значениях.

Comment: d = {'range_1': [26365, 3757, 3723], 'range_2': [-275.08, 757.74, 668.44], 'range_3': [-1, 0, -1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

Comment: @AlexSCH у вас в вопросе  `range_3=[-1,1,-1]`  а здесь пишите  `[-1,0,-1]` .Если прибавлять  `0`  то цикл никогда не закончится

Answer (score 0):

Я вообще не понял зачем здесь циклы.
Если разбить задачу на этапы, то

1. Найти индекс максимального элемента в столбце roundin_1.
2. Проверить, что значением home_label по найденному индексу можно увеличить значение value_1 по найденному индексу до значения sum_1.
3. Просто добавить к этому значению необходимую разницу.

```
sign = lambda x: -1 if x < 0 else 1
def rounding(_label, _roundin, _value, _summ):
    max_roundin = max(_roundin)
    max_index = _roundin.index(max_roundin)
    summ_value = sum(_value)
    increment = _label[max_index]
    delta = _summ - summ_value
    if sign(delta) != increment:
        print("It's impossible to reach the result.")
    else:
        _value[max_index] += delta


label = [-1, 1, -1]
roundin = [-275.08, 757.74, 668.44]
value = [26365, 3757, 3723]
summ = 75644
        
rounding(label, roundin, value, summ)
print(value)
```

```
[26365, 45556, 3723]
```